# UI Frozen / Tried to work with task / async await

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I write a `WPF` Programm which reads the configuration of the PC.

The Programm has to be refreshed an the  `HttpWebRequest` will delay the code so the UI will freez.

I tried to work with `async` / `await` `task`s.

Method in `Class` Network:

```
public TreeView CreatTVURLs()
{
    TreeView TVURLs = new TreeView(); //Here it will break. Says no STA-Thread
    List<CPingables> lURLs = new List<CPingables>();
    lURLs = ReadURLsFromFile();
    TVURLs.Name = "URLs";
    TVURLs.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
    TVURLs.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

    foreach (CPingables item in lURLs)
    {
        tviURL.Items.Add("IP:\t\t\t" + item.IP.ToString());
        tviURL.Items.Add("URL:\t\t\t" + item.URL);
        ... more stuff
```

Tried with `Thread`:
Code in `MainWindow`:

```
 public async void openWindow()
 {
   TreeView tvURLs = new TreeView();
   tvURLs = (TreeView) TreeViewTest();
   //tvURLs = Network.CreatTVURLs();
   StackPanel.Children.Add(tvURLs);
 }

 private TreeView TreeViewTest()
 {
   TreeView tvURLs = new TreeView();
   Thread t = new Thread(() => { tvURLs = Network.CreatTVURLs(); });
   t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   t.Start();
   t.Join();
   return tvURLs;
 }
```

Tried with `Task`:

```
public async void openWindow()
{
  TreeView tvURLs = new TreeView();
  tvURLs = (TreeView) await TreeViewTest();
  Task.WaitAll();
  StackPanel.Children.Add(tvURLs);
}

private Task<TreeView> TreeViewTest()
{
  TreeView tv = new TreeView();
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { tv=(TreeView)Network.CreatTVURLs()});
}
```

I get always says it must me a STA Thread to handle `Form`items.

Edit:

`HttpWebRequest`

```
 public async void pingIP()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_IPPingAvailible == true)
            {
                Ping pinger = new Ping();
                PingReply replyIP = pinger.Send(_IP);
                _PingByIP = replyIP.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _PingByIP = false;
        }
        try
        {
            if (_UrlAvailible == true)
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_URL);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);
                request.Timeout = 1000;                 
                using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        _ReachableByHttp = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _ReachableByHttp = false;
                    }
                }                    
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            _ReachableByHttp = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not try to create instances of UI controls in background threads. These must be done in the main thread. Rather create the data objects in the background thread and then data bind these objects to the TreeView.

Comment: Normaly it works fine. But just only with a freez. Even if i creat labels in the Class. Thats why i am a little confuesd.

Comment: When you run it on the UI thread (which is running in STA) you can create UI controls like that. It's not best practice and not how you utilize the MVVM but you can do it. When you try to create UI elements in background threads it will cause an Exception however.

Comment: Also do not return void with async methods. Return `Task` with no arguments. Otherwise errors won't be picked up.

Comment: where is the code, where you create the `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: Edited the `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 2):

The rule is, that you can access UI elements only in UI thread (called also Dispatcher thread, or main thread). You are breaking this rule. You have cerate new thread by:
`Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` resp by `new Thread(...);`, but you are manipulating the UI elements (treeview) inside the new thread.

Instead, you should perform only the I/O operation or HttpRequest/Response in the new thread, but everything else (e.g. creating treeview from the http response data) should be done in UI thread.

```
public async void openWindow()
{
  TreeView tvURLs = await Network.CreatTVURLsAsync();
  StackPanel.Children.Add(tvURLs);
}

public async Task<TreeView> CreatTVURLsAsync()
{
   //you are in dispatcher thread here, so you can access UI elements here
   TreeView TVURLs = new TreeView(); 
   TVURLs.Name = "URLs";
   TVURLs.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
   TVURLs.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);


   List<CPingables> lURLs = null;
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
      //you are in new thread now, so you cannot access UI elements here
      lURL = ReadURLsFromFile();
   });

   //you are in dispatcher thread again, so you can access UI elements again
   foreach (CPingables item in lURLs)
   {
      var tviURL = new TreeViewItem();
      ..more stuff
      TVURLs.Items.Add(tviURL);
   }
}
```

Comment: I see my mistake. You should add some discription in general. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: Your code works. He make the request simultanlesly but it still freez unti he waits for Response.